# Job interview question

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, semantics

I'm a French man in my late 20s and I'm applying for a job for a prestigious American company. I've had a job interview with an American woman and she told me all was well but I'd have to be molded to be just like ''the rest of the girls and the rest of the skirts.'' It's true, it's mainly a female company. I don't understand this expression. Please explain. Should I be worried or was it a joke?

Comment: What kind of a company are we talking about?

Comment: Perfumes, that's all I can say.

Comment: It might have been meant as a joke (from a different era), but it might also mean that you have to adjust to the culture of working in a team that is mostly female. Not really sure what you mean by "should I be worried", though. Worried about turning into a girl? Why would that be of any concern? As I guy, I know what perfumes I like on women. Does it make me any less of a man? Nope. I just know what I like. Likewise, you'll do your job regardless of your sexual orientation or dress preference.

Comment: Yes, pretty much worried of becoming a chick, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that is _exactly_ how it happens. First you start working with women, then you start dressing like them and before you know it, your reproductive organs are now carried on the inside of your body. I'd be very careful if I were you.

Comment: A river of suits.

Comment: This question should be migrated to the Workplace.SE site.

Answer (score 1):

> molded to be just like ''the rest of the girls and the rest of the skirts.''

I imagine this is a joke: a twist on the more normal (for a male dominated company) phrase that you need to "fit in with the rest of the guys and the rest of the suits".  Here suits is slang for the management.

So you will have to be trained to project the company image, presumably.

Answer (score 0):

In the American corporate environment, there is a lot of pressure to manage expectations and to conform to those around you. If I were in your position, I would assume that this person was suggesting that, since the company is mostly female, I might need to adjust my humor or conversation topics or perhaps even expectations.

If this company is not used to working with Internationals, particularly a young French guy, they might be unsure of how you will get on with your peers, who I assume are mostly young American women. I would not immediately be concerned with the joke. What she said isn't a common expression, but is still sounds like she was trying to make a joke about you being a man and the company being mostly made up out of women.